# create and set variables at same time in a loop tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a label and assign it at the same time.
For example,

```
ivar=StringVar()
for i in range(0,len(str)):
   w = Label(master, textvariable=ivar)
   w.grid(row=r,column=c)
   ivar.set(i)
   r++
   c++
.......
root.update()
```

This is just a sudo example. I just want to generate n labels where I don't know value to n and it changes everytime I update. I am using root.update() for updating labels. Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using the same ivar for all labels so they will all contain the same number (is that the problem you want to solve?).  Note that your code will not run as it, as Python does not support the r++ syntax AFAIK.

Comment: Yeah. It's showing same value in all variables. And I am not using the code as it is. It's just a pseudo code. So there is no other option to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally save them in a list, which is a convenient way to save references to them all.  And please don't use i,l, or o as single digit variables as they can look like numbers, i.e.
i=1
i=l
l=O

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
else:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x

class TestLabels():
    def __init__(self, parent, num_labels):
        self.parent = parent
        self.string_var_list=[]
        tk.Button(self.parent, text="Exit", command=self.parent.quit,
                  bg="orange").grid(row=100)
        self.create_labels(num_labels)

        ## change one label
        str_var=self.string_var_list[10]
        str_var.set("***changed***")

    def create_labels(self, num_labels):
        """create labels, 5 to a row
        """
        r=0
        c=0
        colors=["lightblue", "yellow", "white", "pink", "lightgreen"]
        for ctr in range(num_labels):
            s_var=tk.StringVar()
            ## won't save the Label ID since you use StringVar to change it
            tk.Label(self.parent, textvariable=s_var,
                     bg=colors[c]).grid(row=r, column=c, sticky="nsew")
            s_var.set("Label #%d" % (ctr))
            self.string_var_list.append(s_var)
            c += 1
            if c > 4:
                c=0
                r += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MA=TestLabels(root, 14)
    root.mainloop()
```